# Quick and easy way to expose local docker images like a registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-image

I am looking to a solution to fasten development with docker images and their testing.

Does it exist a solution that would expose all tagged images from a host through a docker registry API ?

This would allow to do:

- docker build
- List item
- docker tags
- **NOT populating a registry**

and have the docker image already available, and usable in kubernetes for example.

I am surprise this doesn't already exists.

How do people iterate on docker images (fixing config, checking everything deploy correctly, etc ...) ?

I was used to do it locally with docker-compose, but using Kubernetes makes a registry mandatory and seems to complicate things a bit more.

Comment: We have a registry set up, and `docker push` a lot during later phases of development (after the service works locally without Docker, passes its unit tests, and a minimal local `docker run` works).

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent wheel? Registries are exactly what are you asking for and everybody uses them as they are. Also I would like to recommend building and pushing docker images in the CI so it'ss transparent.

Comment: You're asking for a registry ("docker registry API" what is the main part of a registry) but you don't want a registry. That could be tricky. I think your options are: AWS / Azure (~ $5 per month). Do it yourself: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#stop-a-local-registry or artifact servers like nexus.